# Overridding a:link

Tags: css

In my main CSS file, I have my a:link selector set to display links in White.

```
a:link{
color: white;
}
```

However, I want links in another DIV (.menuItem) to be black.

I am trying

```
.menuItem a:link{
color: black;
}
```

can't seem to get it to work, so it's probably wrong..

Can anyone lend a hand on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.menuItem a:link{
color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: That's not an ideal solution - should be able to use the cascade effect to make this work.

Comment: @Grant Palin : that is right, css can sort of "override" the general style definition with a more specific one. So having a !important or not should not be critical to the solution

Answer (score 2):

With respect to [Chacha102](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511770/overridding-alink/2511780#2511780), I don't think the solution is ideal. `!important` is a kludge, and a better way to handle this would be to make use of the document structure to add some specificity. Assuming your `.menuItem` elements have a common parent, perhaps a `div` with an id of `menu`, you could revise your menu-specific link style as follows:

```
#menu a:link {
    color: black;
}
```

The extra specificity should cause the more specific rule to take effect for those menu items.

Comment: This is a good suggestion to the html structure, but I reckon the problem comes from embedding css directly into the html page or not. If you take my sample code and access it in XAMP, then you can see the difference. So with repect to the original question, yeah, it is feasible, I am afraid it has to be two files rather than one.

Answer (score 0):

Working on a sample code now. But Is your div tag having an Id of menuItem or a class of menuItem? This is my guess.

Edited : Okay, now I see. If you separate the css to another file and use a link tag to import it in, then it should be fine without using the !important command, see this :

```
body {background-color : green;}

a:link{ color : white;}

.menuItem a:link
{
color : black;
}
```

And this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <a href="#">This is a link</a>
</div>
<div class="menuItem">
    <a href="#">This is a link in div menuItem</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps:)

Still, if I embed the css snippet into the html, then it doesn't work... Wondering why?

Comment: I would think a class, as there are probably many menu items.